# executing query1 if condition is true else query2

Tags: mysql, sql

```
if(condition ,select t1.a,t1.b from t1 join t2 on t2.c=t1.a, select t1.a,t1.b from t1)
```

but when am executing it shows error how to overcome and how to get result

Comment: Add the error here to get better answer.

Comment: Edit your question to show the entire text of the error message.

Comment: please add sample input and output and table structure

Comment: You need a stored proc with if statement (it is different from the if function!) or you need to do this in your application code. If the condition depends on data in t1 table, then you may be able to do the whole thing with a left join.

Comment: Is that your complete SQL statement? If so, what is the value of ```condition``` and how are you setting it? If you show more info, there might be a different way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`if()` can be a function used within a SQL statement.  I discourage this use because the standard construct is `case`.

`if` can also be a control flow construct.  However, this is allowed only in programming blocks (think stored procedures and triggers).

Here are two ways to do what you want in a single query:

```
select t1.a, t1.b
from t1 join
     t2
     on t2.c = t1.a
where condition
union all
select t1.a, t1.b
from t1
where not (condition);
```

Or:

```
select t1.a, t1.b
from t1
where (not condition) or
      exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.c = t1.a);
```

Note that both of these assume that `condition` does not evaluate to `NULL` (although that is easily included in the logic).

Answer (score 0):

First of all mention your full SQL statement,
Documentation for IF is

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Where is your select statement??